# remote Desktop connection from Mac to Ubuntu

Tags: remote

I'm trying to use my MacBook to Remote Desktop connect to my ubuntu server. I am able to ssh, but I can't seem to figure out how to Remote Desktop connect.

Any suggestions? Also my ubuntu workstation is 1200 miles away so I can't physically access it but I can access it through ssh so hopefully I can configure what I need through ssh.

Comment: You might want to look into VNC.  Not my area of expertise so maybe others will have a better solution for you.

Comment: If you set up an X Server on your Mac, then you can set `DISPLAY=1.2.3.4:0` where `1.2.3.4` is your IP address and then you can run X Windows programs directly from SSH and have the window pop up on your Mac. Try with `xterm`.

Comment: This exact issue appears to have been asked and answered here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/304017/how-to-set-up-remote-desktop-sharing-through-ssh

Answer (score 0):

Use VNC or forward X for specific application you run. You can also try `xrdp` which is

Comment: I downloaded VNC yesterday but I was having a very hard time configuring the settings on Ubuntu through ssh

Comment: This is a "batteries not included" answer.  Can you elaborate on how to accomplish your solutions?

Comment: @fixer1234 There are a lot of tutorials in the internet for each option.

Comment: @David if you can provide more detail, maybe I can help with this problem.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/304017/how-to-set-up-remote-desktop-sharing-through-ssh